# Why are These KML Polygons Not Filled With Assigned Colour in Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, kml

In ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2 I converted a Feature Class into a KML using "Layer to KML (Conversion)".

The polygons in that KML look like this in Google Earth.

[image]

Why are (most of) the polygons rendering "oddly", that is, lacking a solid fill colour, and often mostly entirely absent?

---

@MichaelStimson provided the solution (to run Repair Geometry tool).  See results below.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have geometry errors in your source data, run Repair Geometry http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000 on the source data prior to export and see if that helps.

Comment: Bingo.  Thanks, but it still seems odd to find out that apparently my perfectly-rendered FC in Arc had "errors" that prevented it from rendering correctly in Google Earth.  I've added a screen shot in my original question.  Feel free to move your comments to a solution and I will up vote.

Comment: This question lead to a secondary question but I will adhere to the "one question per question" policy.  My secondary question is here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287769/how-to-render-kml-hatched-polygon-symbology-in-google-earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your geometries have errors, either self intersections or incorrect ring orientations which make them unsuitable to display in KML. According to https://github.com/Ecotrust/madrona/issues/186 KML insists on clockwise (exterior?) ring orientation.

Run [Repair Geometry](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000003v000000) on your data before exporting to KMl to fix common geometry problems.

Repair geometry is the first thing I do when a feature class doesn't behave as it should.