# How to Render KML "Hatched" Polygon Symbology in Google Earth?

Tags: symbology, kml, google-earth

After solving the issue of KML polygons that were only partially filled-in in Google Earth (here: [Why are These KML Polygons Not Filled With Assigned Colour in Google Earth?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/287763/why-are-these-kml-polygons-not-filled-with-assigned-colour-in-google-earth)) I'm now wondering how to make Google Earth display the hatched colouration fill of certain polygons.

Here is how they look in ArcMap.

[image]

Here you can see that Google Earth simply renders the hatched polygons as solid black.

[image]

How can I render these KML Polygons in Google Earth with their true "Hatched" Symbology?  (or is it even possible?)

Comment: KML does not support a hatched renderer https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kml-support-advanced/KATMRtLHXlo , only a simple polygon fill. Perhaps in a new version of KML/KMZ there might be support.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  Once again, that is the answer to my question so feel free to answer and I will select as the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately KML (and KMZ) does not support *fancy* fill symbols like markers or hatching.. have a read of https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kml-support-advanced/KATMRtLHXlo which was asked in **2007**, so I wouldn't consider hatching and stipples will be part of the KML standard any time soon.